# How do I store information in lists

Tags: python, list

My goal is to create a program that checks whether a number is a prime number and displays the total number of factors if it is not a prime number.

I have started the code but I realize I need to store my factors in a list in order for the number of factors to be displayed. Here is my (edited) Python code so far:

```
userNum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("User Number: ", userNum)

numFactors = []
for x in range(1, userNum+1):
       if(userNum % x == 0):
           factor = 0
           numFactors.append(x)
           factor = factor + 1
           print(userNum,"is not a prime number")
           print("Number of factors: ", factor)
           break
       else:
           print(userNum,"is a prime number")
```

Can someone please tell me how to continue with storing factors into my list (numFactors)? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use append()

### Your syntax changed as below.

```
userNum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("User Number: ", userNum)
numFactors = []
for x in range(1, userNum+1):
       if(userNum % x == 0):
           factor = 0
           numFactors.append(x)
           factor = factor + 1
           ...
           ...
```

But there is a **logical flaw** in your code. Try input as **99**.

### Corrected solution

```
userNum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("User Number: ", userNum)
numFactors = []

# A prime number (or prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.
# Hence range starting from 2
for x in range(2, userNum+1):  
       if(userNum % x == 0):
           numFactors.append(x)
if len(numFactors) == 1:
    print(userNum, " is a prime number")
else:
    print(userNum,"is not a prime number")
    print("Number of factors: ", len(numFactors))
    print("Factors : ", numFactors)
```

#### Output

```
Enter a number: 99
User Number:  99
99 is not a prime number
Number of factors:  5
Factors :  [3, 9, 11, 33, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put the line that defines `numFactors`, `numFactors = []`, outside of and before the `for` loop. Otherwise, it will be continually set to an empty list for each iteration of the loop.

Values can be added to the end of a list by using the list's `append` method.  For example, `numFactors.append(2)` would add `2` to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is lacking check whether x is equal to userNum, that is in the end of the loop.

My other suggestion is you remove variable `factor` as this can be known from the length of the numFactors list.

```
userNum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("User Number: ", userNum)
numFactors = []
for x in range(1, userNum + 1):
    if userNum % x == 0:
        numFactors.append(x)

    if userNum == x:
        print("Factors: " + str(numFactors))
        if len(numFactors) == 2:
            print(userNum, "is a prime number")
        else:
            print(userNum, "is not a prime number")
            print("Number of factors: ", len(numFactors))
```